# How to get the nth value of a JavaScript generator?

Tags: javascript, generator, ecmascript-6

How can I get the nth value of a generator?

```
function *index() {
  let x = 0;
  while(true)
    yield x++;
}

// the 1st value
let a = index();
console.log(a.next().value); // 0

// the 3rd value
let b = index();
b.next();
b.next();
console.log(b.next().value); // 2

// the nth value?
let c = index();
let n = 10;
console.log(...); // 9
```

Comment: Have you tried a loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to avoid unnecessary creation of arrays or other intermediate values. Here's what my implementation of `nth` ended up like -

```js
function nth (iter, n)
{ for (const v of iter)
    if (--n < 0)
      return v
}
```

Following the examples in the original question -

```js
// the 1st value
console.log(nth(index(), 0))

// the 3rd value
console.log(nth(index(), 2))

// the 10th value
console.log(nth(index(), 9))
```

```
0
2
9
```

For finite generators, if the index is out of bounds the result will be `undefined` -

```js
function* foo ()
{ yield 1
  yield 2
  yield 3
}

console.log(nth(foo(), 99))
```

```js
undefined
```

Expand the snippet below to verify the results in your browser -

```js
function *index ()
{ let x = 0
  while (true)
    yield x++
}

function* foo ()
{ yield 1
  yield 2
  yield 3
}

function nth (iter, n) {
  for (const v of iter)
    if (--n < 0)
      return v
}

// the 1st value
console.log(nth(index(), 0))

// the 3rd value
console.log(nth(index(), 2))

// the 10th value?
console.log(nth(index(), 9))

// out-of-bounds?
console.log(nth(foo(), 99))
```

Answer (score 6):

You can define an enumeration method like [in python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
function *enumerate(it, start) {
   start = start || 0;
   for(let x of it)
     yield [start++, x];
}
```

and then:

```
for(let [n, x] of enumerate(index()))
  if(n == 6) {
    console.log(x);
    break;
  }
```

http://www.es6fiddle.net/ia0rkxut/

Along the same lines, one can also reimplement pythonic `range` and `islice`:

```
function *range(start, stop, step) {
  while(start < stop) {
    yield start;
    start += step;
  }
}

function *islice(it, start, stop, step) {
  let r = range(start || 0, stop || Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER, step || 1);
  let i = r.next().value;
  for(var [n, x] of enumerate(it)) {
    if(n === i) {
      yield x;
      i = r.next().value;
    }
  }
}
```

and then:

```
console.log(islice(index(), 6, 7).next().value);
```

http://www.es6fiddle.net/ia0s6amd/

A real-world implementation would require a bit more work, but you got the idea.

Answer (score 4):

[As T.J. Crowder pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30410359/how-to-get-the-nth-value-of-a-javascript-generator#comment48907733_30410395), there is no way to get to the `n`th element directly, as the values are generated on demand and only the immediate value can be retrieved with the `next` function. So, we need to explicitly keep track of the number of items consumed.

The only solution is using a loop and I prefer iterating it with [`for..of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of).

We can create a function like this

```
function elementAt(generator, n) {
    "use strict";

    let i = 0;

    if (n < 0) {
        throw new Error("Invalid index");
    }

    for (let value of generator) {
        if (i++ == n) {
            return value;
        }
    }

    throw new Error("Generator has fewer than " + n + " elements");
}
```

and then invoke it like this

```
console.log(elementAt(index(), 10));
// 10
```

---

Another useful function might be, `take`, which would allow you to take first `n` elements from a generator, like this

```
function take(generator, n) {
    "use strict";

    let i = 1,
        result = [];

    if (n <= 0) {
        throw new Error("Invalid index");
    }

    for (let value of generator) {
        result.push(value);
        if (i++ == n) {
            return result;
        }
    }

    throw new Error("Generator has fewer than " + n + " elements");
}

console.log(take(index(), 10))
// [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ]
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple loop will do:

```
let n = 10,
    iter = index();
while (--n > 0) iter.next();
console.log(iter.next().value); // 9
```

Comment: As [the iterator interface](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-iterator-interface) doesn't define much of anything else than `next`. :-)

Comment: I did like Qantas 94 Heavy's lateral thinknig with `Array.from`, though of course it has consequences (consumes all of the generator's values, and as you pointed out in a comment on his now-deleted CW, it would be ... problematic ... with an infinite generator).

Comment: One could do `Array.from(iter_take(index(), n))[n-1]` of course

Comment: …or even better, `iter_drop(index(), n-1).next()`

Comment: Those are just names you've come up with yourself, right? For hypothetical functions written as loops like the above? (Just for the avoidance of doubt, as they aren't in the spec [nor in the usual naming convention used in the spec].)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Yes, I came up with them myself. `take` and `drop` are standard names for the respective list operations, and I used the `iter_` prefix that these specific implementations should work on iterators.

Answer (score 3):

You could create an array of size *n*, and use `Array.from` and its second argument to fetch the values you need. So assuming `iter` is the iterator from generator `gen`:

```
var iter = gen();
```

Then the first *n* values can be fetched as follows:

```
var values = Array.from(Array(n), iter.next, iter).map(o => o.value)
```

...and when you are only interested in the *n<sup>th</sup>* value, you could skip the `map` part, and do:

```
var value = Array.from(Array(n), iter.next, iter).pop().value
```

Or:

```
var value = [...Array(n)].reduce(iter.next.bind(iter), 1).value
```

The downside is that you still (temporarily) allocate an array of size *n*.