# How do you get the key at specifc index in javascript map object?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Suppose I have the following map object

```
const items = new Map([['item1','A'], ['item2','B'], ['item3', 'C']])
```

I want to fetch the key at index 2. Is there a way other than using a for loop to get the key of item at index = 2 ?

Got this working as per the answer -

```
Array.from(items.keys())[2]
```

Comment: related: [How to get a last element of ES6 Map without iterations?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30921283/1048572)

Comment: why not use array for this purpose?

Comment: `Array.from(items.keys())[2]` is identical to `[...items.keys()][2]`, both allocate the complete array of keys. If you want to avoid that, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30410359/how-to-get-the-nth-value-of-a-javascript-generator

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Maps might be ordered, but they are not indexed. The only way to get the *n*th item is a loop.

Comment: What a shame... any TC39 people here wanna weigh in on why they're not indexed?

Comment: @geoyws Because that's not their purpose? If you want an indexed collection, use an array.

Comment: I'm looking for a solution that allows me to have a collection of keys and values that are ordered & indexed... Arrays can't do keys and values and require looping to look for a certain "key". Objects aren't ordered and get jumbled up. Maps aren't indexed and require loops to get indexes. It's sad because I thought Maps would solve my problem.

Comment: @geoyws You can build what you want on top of two Maps + an array. One Map to store key-value pairs, one Map to store key-index mappings, one array to store index-key mappings. Make each of the operations (set by key, remove by key, lookup by key, lookup by index) do the right thing to all three of those structures, based on information from the relevant one. This doesn't require language support.

Comment: Apparently, as of ES2015, Objects are ordered... https://codepen.io/geoyws/pen/xWrXEe

Comment: @geoyws ES6 might specify an order (for specific operations, but e.g. not for loops) to keep the behaviour consistent between engines, but that does not mean objects are meant to be used as ordered collections.

Comment: @Bakkot sure it's possible but it's not efficient is what I'm trying to get at :(

Comment: @Bakkot perhaps the other solution is to do new Map([[ myKey, [ myValue, myIndex ]]]) and we'll only need 1 data structure! If you need to iterate over the list, just use .forEach() and everything will be ordered.

Comment: @geoyws Three maps is actually the most efficient you get for support all kinds of operations. You will still need some sort of index->key or index->value lookup method, with insertion/deletion characteristics as you need.

Comment: @Bergi you're right... my idea still lacks the index->value lookup ability... but I do believe my idea still allows us to need only 2 data structures instead of 3. Caveat: Index updates are more expensive vs traditional Arrays (because they're not done natively). Saving Grace: a 3rd key->index lookup Map also requires the same expensive upkeep. If we were to use new Map([[ myKey, { index: myIndex, value: myValue }]]) and mutate myIndex +1 or -1, it's essentially the same as having another Map... regardless, I honestly feel like there should have been a data-type that does all these natively

Comment: Functions and loops...sigh! Just extend the thing and add your own property. I have a class that extends the Map object, and it fires an event when the map is updated so I don't have to query it...SO useful!

Answer (score 37):

To fetch the key at index 2, do the following:

```
// Your map
var items = new Map([['item1','A'], ['item2','B'], ['item3', 'C']]);

// The key at index 2
var key = Array.from(items.keys())[2];                 // Returns 'item3'

// The value of the item at index 2
var val1 = items.get(key);                             // Returns 'C'


// ... or ...
var val2 = items.get(Array.from(items.keys())[2]);     // Returns 'C'
```

Comment: More concise but less efficient would just be to get the all the values, if the map is small:  var val2 =  Array.from(items.values())[2];

Answer (score 5):

```js
const a = new Map([['1 Item', 'abc'], ['2 Item', 'def']]);
let indexVal =   [...a][1];
console.log(indexVal);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a more comprehensive solution that doesn't pointlessly copy all of the values into an array:

```
function get_nth_key<K, V>(m: Map<K, V>, n: number): K | undefined {
  if (n < 0) {
    return undefined;
  }
  const it = m.keys();
  for (;;) {
    const res = it.next();
    if (res.done) {
      return undefined;
    }
    if (n <= 0) {
      return res.value;
    }
    --n;
  }
}

const m = new Map<string, string>([['item1', 'A'], ['item2', 'B'], ['item3', 'C']]);

console.log(get_nth_key(m, -1));
console.log(get_nth_key(m, 0));
console.log(get_nth_key(m, 1));
console.log(get_nth_key(m, 2));
console.log(get_nth_key(m, 3));
```

Output:

```
undefined
item1
item2
item3
undefined
```