# How to get the X item in a map?

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is what I have tried that worked, but I don't think it's efficient:

```js
let array = []
map.forEach(item=>{
array.push(item)
})
//1st Item is array[0] 2nd Item is array[1] etc.
```

Comment: can you provide more context? perhaps a code snippet on what you have done. specific item in a map as in?.

Comment: What do you mean by X item?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37822141/how-do-you-get-the-key-at-specifc-index-in-javascript-map-object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with

````
var mapObject = {"one": 1, "two": 2, "three": 3, "four": 4};
var n = 2;
var result = Object.values(mapObject)[n];
console.log(result); // Should print 3. Remember arrays are 0-indexed.```
````

Comment: Alternatively, convert the map into an array with `Array.from()` instead of `Object.values()`